# pam.d errors after OMSA 6.4 upgrade

Tags: dell, pam, dell-openmanage

I have a Dell R710 running CentOS 5.6 x64.  I have it set up to pull Dell's software & patches from their own repos.  This works as well as I can expect it work.  However, I"ve been getting these errors in my system log after the latest OSMA update to 6.4:

```
sfcb[13300]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/common-auth
sfcb[13300]: PAM unable to dlopen(<*unknown module path*>)
sfcb[13300]: PAM [error: <*unknown module path*>: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
sfcb[13300]: PAM adding faulty module: <*unknown module path*>
sfcb[13300]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/common-account
sfcb[13300]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/common-password
sfcb[13300]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

These repeat about 10 times.  Any idea why?

*EDIT 1*

/etc/pam.d directory contents:

```
[root@server pam.d]# ls -alh
total 512K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4.0K Jul 13 06:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 105 root root    12K Jul 28 04:02 ..
-rw-r-----   1 root daemon  390 Jan 26  2010 atd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 26  2009 authconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 26  2009 authconfig-gtk
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 26  2009 authconfig-tui
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    262 Aug  5  2010 bat
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    192 Mar 10 08:32 chfn
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    192 Mar 10 08:32 chsh
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    232 Nov  1  2010 config-util
-rw-------   1 root root    297 Jan  5  2010 crond
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     65 Mar 30 13:01 cups
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     67 Sep  3  2009 cvs
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 27  2009 dateconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    115 Mar 14  2007 eject
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    394 Jun 25  2007 ekshell
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    351 Sep  5  2009 gdm
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    353 Sep  5  2009 gdm-autologin
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    142 Sep  5  2009 gdmsetup
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    412 Aug 28  2010 gparted
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    325 Jun 25  2007 gssftp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    147 Mar 11  2009 halt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 27  2009 hwbrowser
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    115 Jan 20  2009 kbdrate
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    393 Jun 25  2007 kshell
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     70 May 19  2009 ksu
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    644 Mar 10 08:32 login
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep  3  2009 neat
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    172 Apr  2  2010 newrole
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     40 Apr 25 16:44 omauth -> /opt/dell/srvadmin/etc/omauth/omauth.el5
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    265 Dec 17  2010 openwsman
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    154 Nov  1  2010 other
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    103 Aug 11  2010 passwd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Jan 31 17:52 pirut
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    169 Jan 22  2009 pm-hibernate
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    169 Jan 22  2009 pm-powersave
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    169 Jan 22  2009 pm-suspend
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    169 Jan 22  2009 pm-suspend-hybrid
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    147 Mar 11  2009 poweroff
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    138 Jan 20  2009 ppp
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Jan 31 17:52 pup
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    147 Mar 11  2009 reboot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    603 Mar 10 08:32 remote
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    167 Apr  2  2010 run_init
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    143 Mar 30 13:12 runuser
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    105 Mar 30 13:12 runuser-l
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    169 Mar 30 17:51 samba
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     36 May  4 11:23 screen
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     22 Nov  3  2010 serviceconf -> system-config-services
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    145 Mar 29  2007 setup
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    328 Dec 17  2010 sfcb
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     25 Nov  3  2010 smtp -> /etc/alternatives/mta-pam
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     72 May 31 12:29 smtp.postfix
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     72 Mar 31  2010 smtp.sendmail
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     67 Mar 31  2010 squid
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    285 Apr 13 18:53 sshd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    487 Mar 30 13:12 su
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    179 Mar  5 21:56 sudo
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    164 Mar  5 21:56 sudo-i
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    137 Mar 30 13:12 su-l
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     14 Nov  3  2010 system-auth -> system-auth-ac
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    844 Nov  3  2010 system-auth-ac
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Jan 31 17:52 system-cdinstall-helper
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 26  2009 system-config-authentication
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Mar 14  2007 system-config-boot
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 27  2009 system-config-date
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Mar 14  2007 system-config-display
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 May 24  2008 system-config-httpd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Mar 14  2007 system-config-keyboard
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 27  2009 system-config-language
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    103 Jun 27 07:39 system-config-lvm
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep  3  2009 system-config-network
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep  3  2009 system-config-network-cmd
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Mar 14  2007 system-config-nfs
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    118 Sep  3  2009 system-config-samba
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Mar  6 00:54 system-config-securitylevel
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    118 Mar 30  2010 system-config-services
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Mar 14  2007 system-config-soundcard
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Sep 27  2009 system-config-time
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    118 May 24  2008 system-config-users
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Jan 31 17:52 system-install-packages
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    163 Apr 20 12:24 xserver
```

Contents of sfcb:

```
# more /etc/pam.d/sfcb 
# Sample PAM Configuration for Small Footprint CIM Broker
auth       required     pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success user ingroup sfcb
auth       required     pam_localuser.so
auth       include      common-auth
account    include      common-account
password   include      common-password
session    include      common-session
```

It seems that the `sblim-sfcb` package may be broken since the common-* do not exist in /etc/pam.d.  Would I hurt anything by commenting out those lines?

Comment: Please post the content of /etc/pam.d/sfcb and of `ls -alh /etc/pam.d/`.

Comment: Added these to the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The omsa packages musts have added a few files in your /etc/pam.d directory, let's call it omsa; most probably inside the omsa file there are directives like this:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
```

and the PAM machinery is looking for them under /etc/pam.d directory; however, they seems not to be there.

Those files are used to provide 'common' settings for the PAM.

You could check if your login file includes them.

Comment: See my edit in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, neat work by the OMSA developers.
The common- files are typically used in a debian environment (you will also find them in flavours that are based on debian such as ubuntu and mint). They do no exist in redhat based environments.

There are several ways out of this:

1. get the guys from Dell to fix their OMSA package.
2. replace the includes with ones that point to existing files
3. create these 4 files and put the relevant lines inside.

I would post the content of these 4 files for a plain vanilla debian installation, except there is one problem: the content depends on what authentication methods you have enabled/installed on your server. So if you can tell us more about your authentication model, we can probably provide you with the needed lines for these 4 files.

Comment: Well, in it's current state, theoretically something should be broken, right?  I'm not noticing anything that doesn't work, so I'm wondering if I actually need this package.  Maybe it just spilled over into the rpm repo accidentally?